# Up to date receipt proof functionality?

Tags: receipts

I think this repo is a bit out of date: https://github.com/zmitton/eth-proof.

Is there an up to date version that provides receipt proofs for Ethereum?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no updated version of this proof module. The most updated version is 2.1.6, which was published two years ago.